# Optional WHERE comparison in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I come from frontend background and I am trying to write a stored proc that can accept null parameter. Here's a **simplified** version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_item(IN item_id INT(11))
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM item a WHERE a.item_id = IF(item_id IS NULL, a.item_id, item_id);

END;;
```

So I want to `SELECT` everything if `item_id` is null, otherwise, I want the `WHERE` clause to apply. Is this the way to do it? It seems to work, but I am not sure if there is a better way.

I think I can also write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item a WHERE ((item_id IS NULL) OR (a.item_id = item_id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM item a WHERE a.item_id = IF(item_id IS NULL, a.item_id, item_id);
```

is a performance killer: instead of using **no** WHERE, it will evaluate your `IF` for every row, as it is not a constant expression.

```
SELECT * FROM item a WHERE ((item_id IS NULL) OR (a.item_id = item_id));
```

is a good way, as the query planner will see, that the `WHERE` evaluates to a contant expression of `TRUE`

My way would be to put an `IF` into the stored procedure top level, that decides between two queries, one having a `WHERE`, the other not. While this is quite verbouse, it is also quite readable.

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. I did have `IF` at the top level that decides between 2 queries. The problem with that is, it's not `DRY`, you end up repeating code and mine is quite long.

Comment: That's what I ment with verbouse. If it doesn't help readability, don't do it, but use your second query. I outlined the "why" above.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine the way you did:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item a 
WHERE @item_id IS NULL OR a.item_id = @item_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item a 
WHERE a.item_id = COALESCE(@item_id, a.item_id);
```

Comment: Both of which would kill performance by running the WHERE against all rows, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: @EugenRieck Isn't the first statement equivalent to my second one?

Comment: @pixelfreak You are right, I was wrong: The first one is the "good", the second one the "bad" ... first WHERE expression is constant, second is not